# Sorting an array as close as to another array as possible

Tags: javascript

How do I sort an array as close as possible to a target array as possible.

For example:

The array can only contain a maximum of 4 elements:

`['javascript', 'html', 'css', 'result'];`

But in cases where it isn't, the sorting should be as follows:

`['css', 'result', 'html'];` sorted to `['html', 'css', 'result'];`

`['result', 'css', 'javascript'];` sorted to `['javascript', 'css', 'result'];`

The criteria is to get it as close to `['javascript', 'html', 'css', 'result'];` as possible, and where a particular element does not exist, skip it.

My current code seems to do it incorrectly, I've included it below:

```js
function setFiddleTabsArray(updatedFiddleTabs) {
  if (updatedFiddleTabs.length === 4) {
    updatedFiddleTabs = ['javascript', 'html', 'css', 'result'];
  } else {
    const correctFiddleTabsOrder = ['javascript', 'html', 'css', 'result'];
    const fiddleTabsSorter = (a, b) => {
      if (correctFiddleTabsOrder.includes(a)) {
        return -1;
      }
      if (correctFiddleTabsOrder.includes(b)) {
        return 1;
      }
      return 0;
    };
    updatedFiddleTabs.sort(fiddleTabsSorter);
    return updatedFiddleTabs;
  }
  return updatedFiddleTabs;
}

const test1 = setFiddleTabsArray(['css', 'html', 'result']);
console.log(test1);
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: What is the exact criteria for sorting?

Comment: It's hard to make sense from the examples. Why, in the example with the array that includes "result" twice, does the result end up with "html" instead? Why not "javascript"?

Comment: includes is wrong, you should be sorting based on index

Comment: Sorry I've fixed it. The criteria is to get it as close to `['javascript', 'html', 'css', 'result'];` as possible, and where a particular element does not exist, skip it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are always going to get 1 since it is always in the array. You need to sort based on the index of the match

```js
function setFiddleTabsArray(updatedFiddleTabs) {
  if (updatedFiddleTabs.length === 4) {
    updatedFiddleTabs = ['javascript', 'html', 'css', 'result'];
  } else {
    const correctFiddleTabsOrder = ['javascript', 'html', 'css', 'result'];
    const fiddleTabsSorter = (a, b) => {
      return correctFiddleTabsOrder.indexOf(a) - correctFiddleTabsOrder.indexOf(b);
    };
    updatedFiddleTabs.sort(fiddleTabsSorter);
    return updatedFiddleTabs;
  }
  return updatedFiddleTabs;
}

const test1 = setFiddleTabsArray(['css', 'html', 'result']);
console.log(test1);
```

Comment: Thanks this fixes it. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to extract the sort ranking to a separate object and sort with the following logic:

```
const sortRanking = {
  javascript: 0,
  html: 1,
  css: 2,
  result: 3,
};

const setFiddleTabsArray = (updatedFiddleTabs) =>
  updatedFiddleTabs.sort((a, b) => {
    if (sortRanking[a] > sortRanking[b]) return 1;
    if (sortRanking[a] < sortRanking[b]) return -1;
    return 0;
  });

const test1 = setFiddleTabsArray(["css", "html", "result"]);
console.log(test1);
```

This makes it very explicit and easy to follow imo

Answer (score 1):

If you are always sure that nothing besides `'javascript', 'html', 'css', 'result'` will ever be in the array, I would use the `filter` function.

```js
function setFiddleTabsArray(updatedFiddleTabs) {
  if (updatedFiddleTabs.length === 4) {
      return ['javascript', 'html', 'css', 'result'];
  } else {
    const correctFiddleTabsOrder = ['javascript', 'html', 'css', 'result'];
    let result = correctFiddleTabsOrder.filter(element => updatedFiddleTabs.includes(element))
    return result;
  }
}

const test1 = setFiddleTabsArray(['css', 'html', 'result']);
console.log(test1);
```